# How to keep collection alongside playbook and push to own github repo?

Tags: ansible

My current playbook is structured this way

```
projectroot
 |
 |--ubuntu2004
       |
       |--00_setup
             |
             |--vars
             |--playbook.yml
             |--readme.md
```

Because my playbook uses ansible.posix and I also commit my playbook into a github repo. I was hoping if there's a way to include the required collection in this case `ansible.posix` as a requirement and how do I install it?

I saw that there are multiple ways https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html#installing-collections

I was wondering what's the best practice way that makes sense when using a github repository as version control for the playbook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few ways that you could do this. I'd suggest a requirements file since it's the easiest to set up and to manage.

1. Create a requirements file that you use to install the required modules.

   The best way would be to create a requirements file that references the collection(s) your playbook needs. Which you can then use to install the required collection(s) and / or role(s).

   ```yaml
   ---
   collections:
     - name: ansible.posix
   ```
2. Store the module in a repository and install it through `ansible-galaxy`.

   You could upload the module to a git repository and then install it. I wouldn't recommend this as storing dependencies in your source-code isn't considered a good practise when there's a tool to manage dependencies available.

   ```sh
   ansible-galaxy collection install 
   git+https://github.com/organization/repo_name.git,devel
   ```
3. Install the module through a playbook

   I've set up a master node to run playbooks on with Ansible before and installed modules through the `command` task in a playbook. As long as you don't reference / include any tasks or plays that use the module, this will work fine.

   ```yaml
   - name: Install ansible posix module
     command: ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix
   ```

The ideal way would be to have to playbook install the required module(s) prior to executing the tasks. However it's not possible to ignore the error that is thrown when a module is missing, so you would have to have to create a play that doesn't include / reference any of the tasks using the module.

Comment: I think this is the better way to do it too @rpm192

Comment: so i put requirements.yml adjacent to playbook.yml?

Comment: Yes, you create a `requirements.yml` file and put it in your source control. Usually in the root directory or wherever your playbook resides.